# 'tmp' directory is too big in iOS

Tags: ios, directory, tmp, recycle-bin

I made an app which is 40 MB (very big for me).

But the real surprise is that I found the `tmp` directory is 300 MB!

And I haven't saved any files in the document yet!

All the files' names in `tmp` are like:

```
stack-logs.80127.MyAppName.index
stack-logs.80163.MyAppName.vwnxgi.link
...
```

What are these things? They occupied an unbelievably 300 MB size!

Is there a way I can clear them periodically? Or is this because I'm debugging my app on my iPhone?

Answer (score 21):

Edit you target scheme, and close *Logging* → *Malloc Stack*. Uncheck it.

Comment: My app was over 27GB in size and this fixed it, thank you

Comment: Mine grows to 76 GB. That's insane. I almost forgot I checked this option to find memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

The `NSTemporaryDirectory()` function returns a path to the temporary directory for the current user (not just the application's), so these 300 MB are probably files from other applications using the temporary storage.

Comment: Thanks, so can I just delete the files in my app's tmp directory?

Comment: You can, since you have the ownership, but it might cause problems with other apps that share it (cached data, etc.).

Comment: @alexander on iOS the NSTemporaryDirectory is private to the app so this is from your app.